# What Happened to Page Scrolling Outside of Fancybox2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I just updated an app to jQuery 1.9 and upgraded to FancyBox 2.0.  I liked when the outside page scrolled when Fancybox was visible.

Was this featured removed?  Maybe for it's new responsiveness. I can't find it mentioned in the API or updates.  I am getting a shift because of the outside scrollbar being hidden when Fancybox is toggled.  Something I will fix if the outside page scrolling featured has been removed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

With fancybox 2, scrolling the outside page is `locked`, however you can enable/disable that feature within the `helpers` option like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false // if true (default), the content will be locked into overlay
        }
    }
});
```

If you also want fancybox to scroll along the page, add the API option `autoCenter`  and set it to `false`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false // if true, the content will be locked into overlay
        }
    },
    autoCenter : false // fancybox will scroll along the content
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/suvtP/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for answering "not a real question".  Works like expected.I will remember to ask better questions next time...